# How do I get MPAVController "setting movie path"

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I'm developing a video app using UIWebView.

MPAVController launch when connect to video sites, Movie URL is displayed in the debug console.

**Example:**

```
2012-10-17 04:50:57.391 MovieApp[43145:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2012-10-17 04:50:57.392 MovieApp[43145:14003] setting movie path: 【MOVIE URL】
2012-10-17 04:50:57.392 MovieApp[43145:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
```

How do I get "setting movie path"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`MPAVController` is entirely private and you are not supposed to do anything directly on its instance.